# How to updates values of another recyclerview while onClick of recyclerView item

Tags: android

I have two recyclerviews in an activity.One show list of students in class with few details and onclick of each student it should show details of each student. It gets data in JSON array format after a volley call. From webservice call I fetch all the data, but display few details in the second recyclerview. What I'm trying to achieve here is to display the remaining data from that webservice call to another recyclerview onClick of a recyclerview item. I have implemented two adapters successfully. But not sure how to update data in the first recyclerview.

Answer (score 0):

for example if your data is
`{"students":
["student_id":"1" ,""student_details":{"name":"test"}
]
}.`

```
then pass all student data to first and second adapter
but in first adapter show student data and on recylcer item click listener 
just notify second adapter with  student id to change student details based on 
it
```